# Authentication write a dynamic data in _LogOnPartial.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I am a beginner in ASP.net and i  have  MVC 3 C# project with Razor engine. How can i get a property from db context EF in the view _LogOnPartial.cshtml replacing the **@User.Identity.Name**

for example after authentication i have to display the : Welcome ( customer_Name ) [LogOff]

here is the code of _LogOnPartial.cshtml :

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{

<text>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!
[ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
}
else {
@:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one method in your data layer and called it in your view

View

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{

<text>Welcome <strong>@YOURNAMESPACE.getName(User.Identity.Name)</strong>!
[ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
}
else {
@:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}
```

Data Layer

```
 public string getName(string username)
    {
        using (var context = new yourdbcontext(tenantId))
          {
             return context.Users.Where(a => a.UserName == username).Select(a => a.customer_Name ).SingleO 
          }
    }
```